# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I keep getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Chrome. Also, tried including the js file just after the closing body tag but doesn't work.

HTML code:

```
<head>
<title>Task 7 | Jquery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/userlist.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search" />

 </body>
```

JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // getting the error here
$('#filter').click(function () {
    $("#filter").hide();
});
});
```

Comment: are you getting this error in other browsers as well or is it just Chrome...? And have you included jQuery script...?

Comment: I'm getting it in Firefox too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you did not include the jQuery Library.

[Download jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) and add it same way you added `jquery/userlist.js` before.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/userlist.js"></script>
```